# Cant create project on TFS 2015 from VS 2013 Update 5

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs-2015

When I try to create a new project in `TFS 2015` from `VS 2013` Update 5, **getting the error:**

> TF400324: Team Foundation services are not available from the server.
>
> Technical inforamtion (for administrator):
> TF200038: You cannot create a team project with your version of Team Explorer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181477.aspx), you have to install VS 2015 to create a team project in TFS 2015:

> You must connect from a client that is at the same version level as TFS. That is, you must connect to TFS 2015 from a version of Visual Studio 2015.

If you don't have a license for your edition of VS for 2015, you can always install Community edition.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs primarily due to corrupt Team Foundation Server cache.

There are several reasons why the cache can go corrupt

*Abrupt closure of TFS services on your machine
*Multiple versions of TFS (2010/2012/2013) configured on your machine
*Upgrade in the version of TFS at server end, but pending upgrade on client machine
*Corrupted installation of TFS client

Solution – Clearing of cache

- Close all instances of Visual Studio
- Open Task Manager and check if any TFS Services are running.  Select
  each of them and click on End Process Tree
- Browse to the folder below and delete all the contents and
  folders%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache
- %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache

Restart Visual Studio and try triggering build

If you are switching from one version of TFS to another, you may require repeating this solution again.If you are using older version of TFS, you may have to navigate to

```
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\
```

and find out the version folder instead of navigating directly.

Post clearing of cache, you will be prompted to rebind your solution to TFS.

Don’t worry this would not let go of your local un-checked-in changes.

Comment: This is a clean installation of TFS 2015 wihout upgrade, except me no one used it